# Write XML to a php file via file_put_contents or use another cache strategy without converting XML to a string

Tags: php, xml, caching

I am pulling XML from a third party url/server and it's too slow when loading, causing a 15-20 second delay when someone visits my map. I can't control the data because it's a third party and they can't push into our database because we have cloud-hosting with no static range of IP addresses. The call happens in a file called xml-map-info.php and I'm trying to run xml-map-info.php once per hour, and save the XML returned to a page on my server called cached-map-info.php - I'm doing this so when I make a call for the XML data on our server, the response is almost instant, instead of having a delayed response from the third party server.

I'm pulling the data from the third party URL with:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');

$file = file_get_contents('third party url');

echo $file;

file_put_contents('cached-map-data.php', $file);
```

I am able to pass $file through with $file_put_contents if I run $file through a function called parseToXml() that converts everything to a string format like so:

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}
```

The problem is that when cached-map-info.php receives the data, it is no longer in XML format but instead it's just a big string. I've tried adding

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
```

and then appending the string to the cached-map-data.php file with:

```
file_put_contents('cached-map-data.php', $file, FILE_APPEND);
```

but I still do not get XML to come through.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to write full XML data to cached-map-data.php without converting it to a string? If I can't write the XML to cached-map-data.php without converting to a string, how do I revert the string data written by the file_put_contents() function back to XML formatted data?

Is there a better way to do this than using file_get_contents() and file_put_contents()?

**Extra Info and things I've tried**

- Making cached-map-data.php an xml file (cached-map-data.xml)
- passing $file through file_put_contents() without doing any conversion to a string or array which gives me

> "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in /www/cached-map-data.php on line 1"

- Using parseToXML($file) to convert $file back to a string
- $file = simplexml_load_string($file);

I'm not sure what else to try, and I've read all answers and any documentation I could find on Stack and PHP.net & W3. I just want to save the XML to cached-map-data.php so that when someone goes to our page, I can use the data already written to cached-map-data.php and not have to make any calls to the third party server. Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Screenshot of raw data from third party server:
[image: Screenshot of raw data from third party server]

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything other than read the file from the remote server and write it to a local file. I don't understand why you're writing XML data to a PHP file. Write it to an XML file and load that when you need it. Unless, of course, your remote server is sending you an HTML rendition of an XML file. Please post a sample of the raw data,

Comment: Screenshot of data from remote server added.

Comment: I think you're over-engineering this. You're getting XML. Why are you writing it to a PHP file?

Comment: For some reason, with cached-map-data.xml I'm getting this error:
"NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(cached-map-data.xml): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /www/xml-map-info.php on line 60"

I do not get permission denied error on cached-map-data.php. They are in the exact same directory. Only thing changed is the ending from .php to .xml

Comment: Then you're fixing the wrong problem. Fix your permissions error, and write an XML file.